# Problem with m4a files

Tags: sound, nautilus, rhythmbox, ffmpeg, gstreamer

Rhythmbox, vlc and totem instantly crash when opening a m4a file.
When I run rhythmbox -d and play a m4a file, I receive this message:

> (rhythmbox:9023): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_structure_new_empty: assertion 'gst_structure_validate_name (name)' failed
>   (09:46:00) [0x26048a0] [connection_closed_cb] rb-metadata-dbus-service.c:218: client >connection closed
>   g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream >returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
>   Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Also, I can't see the properties of m4a files (right-click > Properties crashes Nautilus)

I tried reinstalling all the gstreamer-plugins and deleting the contents of ~/.gstreamer-0.10 to no avail. Also tried purging and reinstalling rhythmbox many times.

I'm not sure if it's related or not, but I had recently installed ffmpeg (the actual one from the ppa (ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg)). Since I thought it could be related, I apt-get remove'd it but it changed nothing.

The same m4a files work with xine and in Audacity, which leads me to believe it's a problem with gstreamer... but I'm not sure what to try next. Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get this problem with all M4A files, or just this one?

Comment: Oh... I only get it with some m4a files, not all. Those that work are AAC, the non-working ones I can't look up under Properties, but they are significantly larger, prob. lossless?

Comment: Looks like a bug (possibly in gstreamer) - report it as such - or type `ubuntu-bug` immediately after such a crash to make the report as easy as possible.

Comment: I really would hesitate to report this as a bug... Most probably my fault.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it :P

The problem was about the ALAC codec, fixed by installing libavcodec-extra-54 (had to uninstall a bunch of other packages, sadly). Then rhythmbox suggested an additional gstreamer plug-in and now everything's fine.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. What packages did you uninstall?

Comment: I did "apt-get install libavcodec-extra-54" and apt-get told me I had to uninstall a list of packages in order to do that and I accepted. For example, I recall Flightgear was among them, so it's really just because they were using something which had to be changed I guess. I didn't remove anything manually.